# How to show progress bar in HTML file while batch-file is running

Tags: html, batch-file, progress-bar

I have written a `Servlet` to run a bat file. This bat file copies content from specified path and then re-starts the server.  I would like to show the progress bar in html page to the end user w.r.t the batch-file progress i.e, progress bar should progress while the files are copying and should show server started after copy completed and restarted the server.

Here is my code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("DoPost is Invoked");
        String buildPath = request.getParameter("buildPath");
        System.out.println(buildPath);
        try {
            File file = new File("C:/Users/Hrushi/Desktop/Html/BuildPath.txt");
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
            fileWriter.write(buildPath);
            fileWriter.flush();
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:/Users/Hrushi/Desktop/Helllo/hello.bat");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("");
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this example to create a progress bar with vbscript and HTA ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23401151/waiting-bar-in-hta-and-css?answertab=active#tab-top